# No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebApplicationContext' available

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-boot-test

I am running a test in spring boot using webflux and springboottest.

```
 buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.SR1'
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
   testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
    testCompile('io.projectreactor:reactor-test')

}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

**Test cases**

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})

class DemoTest {

    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEach(ReactiveWebApplicationContext context) {
        webTestClient = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(context)
                .configureClient()
                .build();
    }
@Test
    void contextLoads() {
}
```

I am getting the following error

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Failed to resolve parameter [org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebApplicationContext arg0] in executable [void demo.test.DemoTest.beforeEach(org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebApplicationContext)]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameter(ExecutableInvoker.java:221)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameters(ExecutableInvoker.java:174)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameters(ExecutableInvoker.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:116)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeMethodInExtensionContext(ClassTestDescriptor.java:302)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$synthesizeBeforeEachMethodAdapter$12(ClassTestDescriptor.java:290)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachMethods$2(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:155)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachMethods(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:134)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:109)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:67)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebApplicationContext' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:340)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.ParameterAutowireUtils.resolveDependency(ParameterAutowireUtils.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.resolveParameter(SpringExtension.java:179)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameter(ExecutableInvoker.java:207)
    ... 59 more
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is my working class

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
internal class ApplicationTest {

    @Test
    fun contextLoads() {
        Assertions.assertTrue(true)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems related to version conflicts between `Spring boot` and `Finchley` so try to downgrade version to `2.0.1` or `2.0.4`.

Move `springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'` to `springBootVersion = '2.0.1.RELEASE'` or `springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'`.

As http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud suggest `2.0.1` with `Finchley.SR1`.

Comment: Finchley should be compatible with all `2.0.x.RELEASE` versions of Spring boot. In fact, Finchley.SR1 is based upon `2.0.4.RELEASE` as seen in the [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Finchley-Release-Notes).

Comment: Have a look http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/ and take a look Finchley version for  'spring-boot-starter-parent'  and also in release notes Finchley.SR1 there is no 2.0.5

Comment: why not try with 2.0.1 if it works or not then try with 2.0.4 as seen latest in release notes

Comment: You could suggest trying that, I just commented because from your answer suggests that Finchley.SR1 isn't compatible with Spring boot 2.0.5, but it should according to the release notes. That the quickstart snippet hasn't been updated isn't a reason why they shouldn't be compatible if the release notes mention they do.

Comment: As i saw on spring cloud and for SR1 it was recommending only 2.0.1 thats why posted but yeah my mistake didn't check release notes, all my suggestions are seems issue related to conflicting between spring boot version and Finchley version so try 2.0.1 or 2.0.4.

Comment: i tried with 2.0.1 but it still giving me same error

Comment: also whenerver  I am importing the gradle project from spring initializer it is not downloading the dependencies and no error is thrown

Comment: that seems the issue as will recommend to ./gradlew clean install as jars might be corrupted not loaded properly.

Answer (score 0):

[As explained in the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-with-mock-environment), you can just add `@AutoConfigureWebTestClient` to your test class and ask Spring Boot to inject an already configured `WebTestClient` instance in your test class.

Something like:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
class DemoTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```